# Donde escribir el access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, api, cors

Tengo que usar una API de Deezer, y me está bloqueando el uso porque no puse el CORS header. Sin embargo no logro entender como ponerlo correcamente, nada de lo que probé está funcionando. Estoy programando con javaScript, y tengo esto:

```
    fetch("https://api.deezer.com/version/service/id/method/?parameters")
    .then(function(response) {


    return response.json() 
  })

  .then(function(resultado) {

    console.log(resultado)


  })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Error: " + error);

   })
```

Comment: Sabes que me parece raro?... que no me aparece un error de headers o unauthorized cuando me meto directamente a la URL que tienes, puede que el error no sea el servidor, porque entonces, porque yo puedo ver el resultado traído por la API y tu no??

Answer (score 1):

Cuando uno realiza una solicitud desde el cliente el header `access-control-allow-origin` lo establece el servidor. Puedes ver aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin . Te recomiendo que usando la consola Web del navegador en el tab de network chequees que valor te esta enviando el servidor para ese header para poder entender por que el navegador falla en esa solicitud.

En este caso el header deberia establecerlo el servidor `api.deezer.com`. No es algo que uno establezca en el cliente.

Comment: @yeinel tiene razon, de hecho eso es algo que no puedes controlar, a menos de que seas propietario de la API y tengas acceso al archivo que te devuelve esa informacion, solo entonces podras establecer tu mismo la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin en el servidor, de hecho esto de la cabecera Access-Control es para evitar que personas que no esten autorizadas tengan siquiera acceso al recurso.